# How can I create a List (or any other collection) of another class property's type dynamically?

Tags: kotlin

This feature is inspired by TypeScript which allows us to create arrays based on the property of another class, whatever that property's type is.

For example assume you have this class in Kotlin:

```
class Person(
 val name: String,
 val age: Int
)
```

And later, somewhere else in the code I want to have a list of names, so I would do something like this:

```
val namesList = List<Person::name>()
```

And Kotlin will know that this will be equivalent to `List<String>()` at compile time.

This avoids me to manually propagate the type of a field I already declared in one place. Plus, if one day the name type changes from `String` to something else, all the collections would get updated automatically.

Can this be done in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

No, Kotlin is very explicit about types. It is a strongly-typed language.

Maybe the closest you could do is define a type alias next to your class and use that:

```
typealias PersonName = String

data class Person(val name: PersonName, val age: Int)
```

and then:

```
val namesList = mutableListOf<PersonName>()
```

However, in most cases you don't have to explicitly write the types anyway because they can be inferred.

```
// Is a List<String> and would automatically update if name type changed
val nameList = personList.map(Person::name)

// Or to get an empty mutable list:
val nameList = emptyList<Person>().map(Person::name).toMutableList()
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard thing to do is to use [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) to extract the type you need:

```
val people = listOf(
    Person("a", 1),
    Person("b", 2),
    Person("c", 3),
)

val names = people.map { it.name } // statically inferred to List<String>
```

If you changed the type of `name` to something else, you wouldn't need to change the `val names = people.map { it.name }` line - the new type will be inferred automatically.